# How to pass multiple variables from ajax to function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How can I pass 2 variables from ajax to function ? 
I can successfully pass 1 variable, but I don't know how to write the code to pass 2 variables. I'm stuck here:

```
<button id ="+data[i].id+" onclick='tahu("+data[i].id+","+data[i].nama+")'>Detail</button>
```

Here is my function

```
function tahu(x, y) {
     window.alert(x);
     window.alert(y);
}
```

Here is my full ajax code

```
function tampilkan() {
    var data_table = ""; 
    var head_table = ""; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "showkaryawan/da",       
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#oo').empty();
            head_table +="<thead><tr class='bg-info'><th width='10%'>ID Karyawan</th><th width='30%'>Nama Karyawan</th><th width='15%'>Action</th></tr></thead>";

            for (var i =0; i<data.length; i++) {
                data_table +="<tr><td>"+data[i].id+"</td><td>"+data[i].nama+"</td><td>"+"<button id ="+data[i].id+","+data[i].nama+" onclick='tahu("+data[i].id+")'>Detail</button>"+"</td></tr>";
            }

          $('#oo').append(head_table);    
          $('#oo').append(data_table);    
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this code throws some errors in the console? You need to make sure your string arguments are quoted when you pass them to a function: Try change `onclick='tahu("+data[i].id+","+data[i].nama+")'` to `onclick='tahu(\'"+data[i].id+"\',\'"+data[i].nama+"\')'`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`
got this error,

Comment: At what line does that error occur? Did you get that error before or after my change or both?

Comment: after using your code,

Comment: is there another method to solve my problem ?

Comment: My suggestion didn't include any `}`-character, so I'm guessing there are more errors. What line did it happen at and what is before, on and after that line? Can you also add your attempt to the question, so we can see how you implemented it all?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried to solve your problem but without actually doing a json request so bear with me.  Firstly,  You are already using jquery for your ajax call so why not leverage jquery for your DOM manipulation as well?  I have written your function to store the id and nama as attributes on the button element and instead of having an inline function call, I have written a click event handler in jquery to execute any time a button (with class detailButton) is clicked.  This function will grab the data-id and data-name from the button itself and should display the information you want, specific to that button.

The final button element:

```
<button data-id ="id" data-name="nama" class="detailButton">Detail</button>
```

and the jquery:

```
//ajax request
function tampilkan() {
    var data_table = ""; 
    var head_table = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "showkaryawan/da",       
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            $('#oo').empty();
        head_table +="<thead><tr class='bg-info'><th width='10%'>ID Karyawan</th><th width='30%'>Nama Karyawan</th><th width='15%'>Action</th></tr></thead>";

            for (var i =0; i<data.length; i++) {

                var id = data[i].id;
                var nama = data[i].nama;

                data_table +="<tr>";
                data_table +="<td>"+id+"</td>";
                data_table += "<td>"+nama+"</td>";
                data_table += "<button data-id ="+id+" data-nama="+nama+" class="detailButton">Detail</button>";
                data_table += "<td></td></tr>";
            }

          $('#oo').append(head_table);    
          $('#oo').append(data_table);    
        }
    });
}


//click event handler
$('.detailButton').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id')
    var nama = $(this).data('nama');

    alert(id);
    alert(name);
});
```

I took the liberty of expanding your data_table concatenation into multiple lines for ease of reading.  Hope this is closer to your final solution.

Comment: im planning to passing more than 2 variables, there is another way to achieve it ?

Comment: This js code has some invalid quoting around the class name on the button. It's also recommended to have quotes around html attribute values.